Create a measure that returns the sum of all orders for country and year in context
I have a table of orders, with contains seller id, order date, amount and country (among other fields). I need a measure that calculates the sum of amounts for the country and year in context. So, for example:

If I create a table visual with fields 'year' and this measure, it will show the total amount for all countries in each year
If I create a table visual with fields 'year', 'country' and this measure, it will show the total amount for each country in each year
If I create a table visual with fields 'date', 'country' and this measure, it will not show the total amount for this day and country, but keeps showing the year total for the country
If I create a table visual with fields 'seller id', 'date', 'country' and this measure, it will override the 'seller id', and keeps showing the year total for the country

This measure, of course, will be affected by any 'year' or 'country' filter active in the dashboard
I will use this measure later for many purposes. For example, filter in the dashboard only the countries that, for the year selected in context, have ordered more than certain amount
Can you help me, please?

please add your table with some rows of dummy data and also the measure that you tried so far. please also explain how/where your measure fails.

Have a look at the ISINSCOPE function.
Your measure could look like:
Your Measure = 
  var thisYear = YEAR(MAX(YourTable[Date]))

  return SWITCH(TRUE(),
    ISINSCOPE(YourTable[Seller Id]) && ISINSCOPE(YourTable[Date]),
      CALCULATE( SUM(YourTable[Amount]), REMOVEFILTERS(YourTable[Seller Id]), REMOVEFILTERS(YourTable[Date]), YourTable[Year] = thisYear),

    ISINSCOPE(YourTable[Seller Id]),
      CALCULATE( SUM(YourTable[Amount]), REMOVEFILTERS(YourTable[Seller Id])),

    ISINSCOPE(YourTable[Date]),
      CALCULATE( SUM(YourTable[Amount]), REMOVEFILTERS(YourTable[Date]), YourTable[Year] = thisYear),

    // else
      SUM(YourTable[Amount])
  )

